# JavaScript learning - how do I push String elements to String Table and Numbers to Numbers Table

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning Java Script because I would like to become Tester.

This is a code that I wrote to sort elements from list which contains numbers and string and push them to another lists.

```js
const table = [1,5,55,23,645,'Arek','Hermiona','Tomek','Irena'];
const tableOfNumbers = [];
const tableOfNames = [];

table.map(elementsPuller => {
    if( typeof(elementsPuller) == String) {
        tableOfNames.push(elementsPuller)
    } else { 
        tableOfNumbers.push(elementsPuller)
    }
})

console.log(`Names elements: ${tableOfNames}`)

console.log(`List elements: ${tableOfNumbers}`)
```

Output is :
Names elements:
List elements: 1,5,55,23,645,Arek,Hermiona,Tomek,Irena

Should be:
Names elements: Arek,Hermiona,Tomek,Irena
List elements: 1,5,55,23,645,

I spent hour to get it working and nothing.

Comment: The result of `typeof` is a string so it returns "string". You have to write `typeof elementsPuller === "string"`. An other thing is: please do not use map to do foreach loop.

Comment: Unrelated, but this is a misuse of `.map()`.  You should be using `.forEach()` here instead.

Comment: Really this should be two calls to `.filter()`, one for the numbers and one for the strings. (Could be done with `.reduce()` I guess, but Mr Crowder doesn't like reduce so I feel bad using it.)

Comment: @Pointy It should be neither `filter()` twice nor `reduce()`, it should be `partition()` - except that doesn't exist in JS ([yet](https://github.com/joaolucasl/proposal-array-prototype-partition)). Or, it seems [the commitee prefers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-filtering/issues/2#issuecomment-810594446) using [`groupBy()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping) (similar to what Nina did below)

Comment: @Bergi yea that'd be nice; I've not heard of it until now.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with type as key and push directly.

Your iteration with `map` is returning an array, but you do not need this.

```js
const
    table = [1, 5, 55, 23, 645, 'Arek', 'Hermiona', 'Tomek', 'Irena'],
    tableOfNumbers = [],
    tableOfNames = [],
    types = { string: tableOfNames, number: tableOfNumbers };

for (const elementsPuller of table) 
    types[typeof elementsPuller]?.push(elementsPuller);

console.log(`Names elements: ${tableOfNames}`);
console.log(`List elements: ${tableOfNumbers}`);
```

With [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const
    table = [1, 5, 55, 23, 645, 'Arek', 'Hermiona', 'Tomek', 'Irena'],
    { string: tableOfNames, number: tableOfNumbers } = Object.groupBy(table, v => typeof v);

console.log(`Names elements: ${tableOfNames}`);
console.log(`List elements: ${tableOfNumbers}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The map() method of Array instances creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map, so it is not the correct method here. What you want is arr.forEach(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
2. you need to use the strict equals operator ( === );
3. typeof "a" returns "string" not String;
4. a nitpick, but elementsPuller is a weird name, 'item' or 'tableItem' sounds better imo;

so the correct code would look something like this:

```js
const table = [1,5,55,23,645,'Arek','Hermiona','Tomek','Irena'];
const tableOfNumbers = [];
const tableOfNames = [];


table.forEach(item => {
    if( typeof item === "string") {
        tableOfNames.push(item)
    } else { 
        tableOfNumbers.push(item)
    }
})

console.log(`Names elements: ${tableOfNames}`)
console.log(`List elements: ${tableOfNumbers}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns the string.

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the operand's value.

```js
const table = [1, 5, 55, 23, 645, 'Arek', 'Hermiona', 'Tomek', 'Irena'];
const tableOfNumbers = [];
const tableOfNames = [];

table.forEach(elementsPuller => {
  if (typeof elementsPuller === "string") {
    tableOfNames.push(elementsPuller)
  } else {
    tableOfNumbers.push(elementsPuller)
  }
})

console.log(`Names elements: ${tableOfNames}`)

console.log(`List elements: ${tableOfNumbers}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) - having an object as accumulator

```js
const table = [1, 5, 55, 23, 645, 'Arek', 'Hermiona', 'Tomek', 'Irena'],
  types = table
    .reduce((acc, element) => (acc[typeof element].push(element), acc), {string: [],number: []})

console.log(`Strings: ${types.string}`)
console.log(`Numbers: ${types.number}`)
```

or reduce where we save ALL types of elements using a [Nullish_coalescing_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) ( the `??=`) to create an array per passed  type.

```js
const table = [1, 5, 55, 23, 645, 
'Arek', 'Hermiona', 'Tomek', 'Irena', 
["a","b","c"], () => alert('Hello')
];
const types = table
  .reduce((acc, element) => {
acc[typeof element] ??= []; // nullish coalescing assignment
acc[typeof element].push(element);
return acc ;
  },{});

Object.entries(types)
  .forEach(([key,value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${key === 'object' ? 
    JSON.stringify(value[0]) : value}`)
  );
```

Comment: `else return !isNaN(element)`???

Comment: The downvote is for the general weirdness of the approach: mixing `filter` and `push`, mixing `typeof` and `isNaN`, returning `undefined` from the callback… This is just hard to understand, possibly incorrect, and definitely not useful for a beginner

Comment: That's better, but I still like dislike abusing `reduce` for mutation, a conventional loop would be suited better

Comment: I disagree it is an abuse. It contains the _"filtering"_ in one statement and has only one result. It is doing in principle the same as Nina's but in one statement.

Comment: Yes, but packing multiple statements in a single expression/statement without any tangible benefit (such as becoming point-free, shorter, etc) just makes it more unreadable imo. `reduce` imo should only be used with pure functions.

Comment: Here there are no unrelated "multiple statements" there is a set of necessary statements and a an initialisation of the necessary container of what we want to extract. I love reduces like the second one I posted. It is much harder to break when the input changes.